# Raspberry pi -Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-tutorials

Tags: ros, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am trying to follow the tutorials in wiki to install the ROS and learn something about it. I had successfully installed the ROS following the instructions here http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi . Then I tried to learn some basic knowledge about it in tutorials. But when I came to this part http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes , and I type
***sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-tutorials*** and it  returns ***Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-tutorials***. Well then I kept going because I can see the turtle in the monitor. But when I came to the next part, and i requires me to ***install ros-indigo-rqt***, and it still returns ***unable to locate package***.

So I think maybe someone can help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201405/raspberry-pi--unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-ros-tutorials/) by [blackey](https://answers.ros.org/users/21430/blackey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. Found a solution in the end of tutorial you linked. You have to change the name of the packages

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws

$ rosinstall_generator ros_tutorials --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
```

Next, update the workspace with wstool:

```
$ wstool merge -t src indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
$ wstool update -t src
```

it downloaded the package for me but you have to add ros_catkin_ws to workspace path

now I have  a new problem when i am trying to run rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node I am getting this message

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named turtlesim_node below /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim

---

Originally posted by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) with karma: 110 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2015-07-08**:
Ok i am updating my status my turtlesim is working properly now without any problems if you have any questions feel free to ask maybe i would be able to help
btw sorry for my bad english :)

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-23**:
Can u tell me how u did this ?

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2015-10-23**:
Can you install tutorial packages or which error message do you get. I gave you commands for installing tutorial packages. It worked for me.

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-23**:
I had a problem with install but I did this with your commands. Now i have problem with turltesim_nodes

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2015-10-24**:
Did you ran catkin_make ?

Try this command and send me what you got from console you probably did not setup your workspace correctly.

```
$ printenv | grep ROS
```

And tell me where is your ros_catkin_ws My is at /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-24**:
`ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pi/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
My ros_catkin_ws is the same place where yours.

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-24**:
And when i try use catkin_make in ros_catkin_ws i have
pi@~/ros_catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src
The specified base path "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the the root of workspace

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2015-10-24**:
ok so open your .bashrc file

```
$ cd
$ nano .bashrc
```

and put this two lines of text at the end of the file

source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

source ~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

and save the file restart your console and try catkin_make or running the turtlesim

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-24**:
Nothing has change. I have the same messages.

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2015-10-24**:
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pi/catkin_ws/src  how you got this path there should be  ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src  do you have catkin_ws or ros_catkin ws as your working directory ?

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-27**:
I dont know. I installed ros by tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi and created ros_catkin_ws after that i go to "core ros tutorial" and create new ros workspace: catkin_ws.

**Comment by [Grzybek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24814/grzybek/) on 2015-10-27**:
Next step was to install tutorial_package so i install it with your command. But ros cant find it by "roscd ros_tutorials" so i logout and log in as root. I copied dir with tutorials to /opt/ros/indigo/share/ And now ros can find this package. I use roscore , ros make turtlesim

**Comment by [Chickenman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23105/chickenman/) on 2015-10-28**:
ok so you can use turtlesim now yeah ?. I am not verry skilled at ROS. On my Pc i am using catkin_ws but on raspberry i am using ros_catkin_ws as worskpace and i did not created another catkin_ws (which creation was described in "core ros tutorial") because it did not work for me well.